# Why does my method work in my API, but not in a test class?

Tags: java, testing, gson, inputstreamreader

I have a problem with unit testing a functionality.

```
public User[] fetchUserByStarsAscendingOrder(String username) throws IOException {
    User[] user = fetchUser(username);
    Arrays.sort(user,Collections.reverseOrder());
    return user;
}   

public User[] fetchUser(String username) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("https://api.github.com/users/" + username + "/repos");
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());

    User[] user = new Gson().fromJson(reader, User[].class);

    if (user == null) {
        logger.error("No input provided.");
        return null;
    } else {
        logger.info("The output returned.");
        return user;
    }
}
```

The above method works just fine in my API, no troubles whatsoever.

BUT when I try to use it in my test class, with the same parameter... it suddenly returns null:

```
class UserServiceTest {
        UserService userService;
        User aUser;
        
        @Test
        void shouldReturnArray() throws IOException {
            //given
            String name = "pjhyett";
            //when
            User[] resultArray = userService.fetchUserByStarsAscendingOrder(name);
            //then
            assertThat(resultArray[0]).isEqualTo(aUser);
        }

        @BeforeEach
        void setUp() {
            aUser = new User();
            aUser.setFull_name("pjhyett/github-services");
            aUser.setDescription("Moved to http://github.com/github/github-services");
            aUser.setClone_url("https://github.com/pjhyett/github-services.git");
            aUser.setStars(408);
            aUser.setCreatedAt("2008-04-28T23:41:21Z");
        }
```

All the above data is taken from GitHub API and are about public repos. I am reaching for the first element in the array because the method returns a couple of results for the array.

IDE tells me that the method that works perfectly in the API itself... returns a null in a test class.

Why is that?

Comment: A guess: your test infrastructure doesn't match your application context. You say "unit test" but provide to evidence of mocking the network requests. So this appears to be integration testing that would require your entire application context to be able to run.

Comment: You don't mock anything, that's way it doesn't work as you want

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate? How do I check if my test infrastructure and my application context match? I have other applications that structurally look basically the same or alike and only here I have problems. And what should I mock about this method? I provided a test case for the testing method that should match exactly what the method returns with its current URL.

Comment: Like the others point out, it's not really a unit test.

However, in the current test setup you're never instantiating the `UserService`so I guess that is causing the NPE.

Comment: Indeed, instantiating UserService resolved my problem... There's no more null and now I'll try to approach the test itself in another manner - I will try to test actually how my code behaves with the given input without basically testing an external API. Thanks a lot for the help. :) @Wouter van der Linde, you could post this comment as an answer, so I can mark it as the one that resolved the issue.

Comment: Awesome. :) Good to read you resolved the issue. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Instantiate `UserService` in the initialization method.**

You're getting the NPE because `UserService` is never instantiated. Consider instantiating the variable in the `setUp()` method.